# Is it possible to pass default parameters to a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, parameters, default

I have a `__str__` method that takes some optional parameters (default is set to None).  If these parameters are not specified, it returns a str that shows the full matrix.  If the optional parameters are specified, it returns a partial matrix corresponding to those values.

```
def __str__(self, starting_row=None, starting_col=None, nrows=3, ncols=3):
    # remove that final space
    string = ""
    for i in range(starting_row, nrows):
        for j in range(starting_col, ncols):
            string += str(self.get(i, j))
        string += "\n"
    return string
```

My code works if `starting_row` and `starting_col` are specified to integer values (e.g. `starting_row=1`).  However, if these values are not specified, since the default value is None, I am getting an error.

What would be the most pythonic way to specify a `starting_row` and `starting_column` of 0 ONLY IF the user does not specify the `starting_row` within the function parameters?  Is there a way to do so in the for loop parameters?

Comment: Having a default of `0` for the parameters would achieve what you want?

Comment: I don't think this is anything to do with the loop parameters. If you don't want `0` as the default parameter, say `if starting_row is None: starting_row = 0`, etc.

Comment: It's already pretty unpythonic to overload `__str__` in this way.

Comment: `__str__` overloading shouldn't have any parameters, they should be computed or fonud from object props

Comment: More pythonic would be to set default value as Falsely.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the default values for the parameters.
This is because in your case, the default value `None` for `starting_row` has no meaning, according to you. Since you want it to default to 0, then do just that.

```py
def __str__(self, starting_row=0, starting_col=0, nrows=3, ncols=3):
    string = ""
    for i in range(starting_row, nrows):
        for j in range(starting_col, ncols):
            string += str(self.get(i, j))
        string += "\n"
    return string
```

Pedantic note:
String concatenation like that is expensive, because strings aren't mutable in python so you're essentially creating new strings in every step.
A better alternative would be to append those values to a list and then perform a join at the end.

Pedantic note2:
Also, this most likely is a method belonging to your class(as you have a self in there), so perhaps a cleaner way to go about it would be to not have parameters at all for the `__str__()` and instead make use of instance attributes

Comment: Thanks.  My instructor has specified the starting_row to have a default value of None, but I agree that it makes more sense to have the default value at 0.  Thanks for the comment about the string join.